# Bare import jsPDF throws error when importing using webpack or expressjs. How to import dependency properly?

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, import, jspdf

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jspdf". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

**OR**

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js' does not provide an export named 'jsPDF' (at 8205f9167920f5638297.js:1:10)`

**OR**
`GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

This is the import statement I m using with variations and errors as shown above
`import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"` 
**How do I get the import statement to work in my project? I'm new to webpack and express implementation and usage, so all help is appreciated.**

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
function downloadToPDF() {
   var canvas = document.querySelector('#datavulnerabilities');
    //creates image
    var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

   var newCanvas = document.querySelector('#attackfrequencies');

   //create image from dummy canvas
    var newCanvasImg = newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
    
    var newCanvas2 = document.querySelector('#attacktypes');
   //create image from dummy canvas
    var newCanvasImg2 = newCanvas2.toDataURL("image.png", 1.0);
    // creates PDF from img
    var doc = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'p',
  ///////code omitted for brevity
```

**Want to use jsPDF to print pdf of charts but cannot get it to work in webpack or expressjs.**